# COUNT DISTINCT CASE expression for PostgreSQL Issues

Tags: postgresql, case, distinct

I am trying to count the unique values of a `position_id` while also satisfy another criteria of "true" in another column. I keep getting all values returned since I am counting them.

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN p.position_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    WHEN internal_only = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS I_Roles
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That would only count the distinct values coming back from the `case` expression (which are 1, 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filtered aggregation:

```
count(distinct position_id) filter (where internal_only = 'true')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count values for true values of `internal_only` using:

```
count(distinct case when internal_only = 'true' then p.position_id end)
```

Comment: So I need to count the distinct values of [position_id] AND when those distinct position ID's are marked as "true" in the internal only column.